# Returning a derived type from factory class

Tags: c#, interface, entity-framework-5, factory-pattern

I have a factory class with this method signature

```
 public static PortfolioUnitOfWork<IPortfolio> GetPortfolioUnitOfWork(string supplier)
 {
 }
```

The `PortfolioUnitOfWork` is a generic object, which can take different Portfolio types.

```
public class PortfolioUnitOfWork<T> :Abstracts.UnitOfWork<T> where T:class, Data.Interfaces.IPortfolio
{
}
```

The idea here, is a string is passed into the factory, from that string it could return `PortfolioUnitOfWork<Type1>` or `PortfolioUnitOfWork<Type2>` etc. `Type1` and `Type2` would inherit from `IPortfolio`.

When trying to set return items for this factory class method, I have the error

```
cannot convert expression type PortfolioUnitOfWork<Type1> to return type PortfolioUnitOfWork<IPortfolio>
```

The IPortfolio interface has no methods, just a number of properties

```
public interface IPortfolio
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

The Portfolio types are EntityFramework Entities, but I have a partial class for each, in which the entity is inherited from the interface. They also have a few non-mapped properties as a result of that.

I would have thought using `PortfolioUnitOfWork<IPortfolio>` as the return type would allow the factory class to return the correct PortfolioUnitOfWork as required. Any ideas why the error might occur?

//Edit

Strangely, in the Factory Class if I set the return type to

```
return new PortfolioUnitOfWork<IPortfolio>()
```

There is no immediate error showing in the IDE (didn't do a build though). I would have thought that would be invalid as `T` inherits from class in the `PortfolioUnitOfWork` class

This does not work either, same error.

```
PortfolioUnitOfWork<IPortfolio> porfolio = new PortfolioUnitOfWork<Type1>();
```

Something like this DOES work, showing the `Type1` implements the correct interface

```
IPortfolio test = new Type1();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because generic types are [invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) by default in c#. It means you cannot do following:

```
List<object> list = new List<string>();
```

or in your case

```
PortfolioUnitOfWork<IPortfolio> porfolio = new PortfolioUnitOfWork<Type1>();
```

And you can't do them variant, because in .NET only interface and delegate type parameters can be variant. Following error appears when you try:

> Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant.

Possible way to go? Create `IPortfolioUnitOfWork`:

```
public interface IPortfolioUnitOfWork
{ }
```

And change your `PortfolioUnitOfWork<T>` to implement that:

```
public class PortfolioUnitOfWork<T> : IPortfolioUnitOfWork where T: class, IPortfolio
```

now you can do following:

```
IPortfolioUnitOfWork porfolio = new PortfolioUnitOfWork<Type1>();
```

ofc, you'll have to change your return statements and variable types from `PortfolioUnitOfWork<IPortfolio>` to `IPortfolioUnitOfWork`.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, This will do the trick. I need to refactor first as my interfaces have reference to another interface<T> which will cause issues if I make T invariant. Thanks for clearing that up for me.